# Update not working from grid view (not able to get the error )

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, windows

I'm trying to update a table from the gridview of tool to the SQL database. The problem is it's not getting updated in the database.

Below is my code for the button click which updates the database:
while debugging the code i found that the data table DT is fetching only the source values not the updated one in the grid view....

Is there any property in the grid view which accepts these change and updates the DT table  ?

```
    public partial class BusinessRules : Form
    {
    //Declaration Part
    private SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=AnimalProductsCoSD;Integrated Security=True");

    private string sqlconn;  // query and sql connection

    private SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter();

    DataTable DT = new DataTable();
    SqlCommandBuilder scb = new SqlCommandBuilder();

   private void button_retreive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string commandText = "CoSD.RetreiveBusinessRulesTool";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BusinessType", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 60).Value = comboBox_BusinessType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CommodityGroup", SqlDbType.VarChar, 60).Value = comboBox_group.Text;
        try
        {

            con.Open();
            SDA.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DT = new DataTable();
            SDA.Fill(DT);
            int count1 = DT.Rows.Count;
            if (DT.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dataGridView.DataSource = DT;
                dataGridView.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
                dataGridView.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;           
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Business Rules Found");


            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }

    }

private void button_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to Update these values?", "Confirm Update", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(SDA);
                SDA.Update(DT);
                // confirm
                MessageBox.Show("Updates successfully submitted to CoSD");

            }

            else
            {
                return;
            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
        }


}
```

Comment: **1.** Why do you set the data source of grid while saving? **2.** How do you create the `SDA` data adapter? Please add its code to the question. **3.** How do you fill and edit `DT` datatable. Please add its code to the question.

Comment: @RezaAghaei... Hi I have edited the question please check the code now....

Comment: You may find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36274706/3110834) helpful.

Comment: @RezaAghaei... Thanks... I tried but it didnt work.... the problem is im poulating the data in the gridview from a stroed procedure execution storing the output of the SP into a data table and then i;m trying to update the table with the displayed columns from the gridview... which the code shown is not working...

Comment: I Also tested the linked answer using a stored procedure and it worked properly.

Comment: Where did you defined DT?

Comment: AT the start of the form --- > DataTable DT = new DataTable();

Comment: Now The source you provided can't help us to help you. Write a really simple code to reproduce the problem. Then you will find the problem or if you couldn't find the problem, post your simple code here. Then we can help you using the code. :)

Comment: I followed instruction of the linked answer using a stored procedure and I could get expected result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107904/discussion-between-gowtham-ramamoorthy-and-reza-aghaei).

Comment: Hi I Update the code section... with my new edits.... please let me know if this information enough.... Please note my gridview column names in dispaly is different from the actual column names since it is the stored procedire that returns the data from database with readable names to display in grid view

Comment: The codes seems OK and there is no obvious problem in code.

Comment: If you want to find the problem, you should create a simple table for example with 2 columns. Then create a stored procedure with 1 parameter which gets the records. Then test using this simple stored procedure. This way you will find the possible points where you may have problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the try, put this

```
 scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
            sda.Update(dt);
```

In your initializer call

```
  SqlDataAdapter sda= new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM someWhere", connectionString);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

The problem is that you refresh the datagridview before submitting the changes, thus deleting anything inputted

**** **EDIT** ****

This is exactly what my code in a project I did a little while back looks like:

```
namespace TowerSearch
{
    public partial class EditParts : Form
    {
        const string conString = ConString.conString;
        static DataClasses1DataContext PartsLog = new      DataClasses1DataContext(conString);
        static Table<Part> listOfParts = PartsLog.GetTable<Part>();

        SqlDataAdapter sda;
        SqlCommandBuilder scb;
        DataTable dt;

        public EditParts()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Load and refresh the dataGridView
        private void showData()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Parts", con);

            dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }

        private void EditParts_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           showData();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                dataGridView1.Refresh();
                scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
                sda.Update(dt);

                MessageBox.Show("Saved");
                showData();
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is an error in the data!\nCheck if there are any blank spots besides Quantity.");
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

That definitely works, so try the code with the show data. I'd suggest just copying it verbatim first to see if it would work.

**** **EDIT** **2** ****

Another thing that you could try if you haven't managed to get it already is add a bindingSource. To do this, drag a bindingSource onto your dataGridView and then set the DataSource option to the table of the DB that you wan't to display

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for the input... however if remove those 2 line codes dataGridView.Refresh();
            dataGridView.DataSource = DT;                                                       I'm still not able to update the table in my database.

Comment: I added more example code, so just try it like that

Comment: I just have  a quick question... In the DT (data table), would that DT need to look similar to the table we need to update ? I mean will the DT dispalyed in the gridview need all the columns as of in the backend database ?

Comment: What happens with the dt is that it is a whole separate temporary table. So, the dt is updated instead of the db. When you update the sda with the dt, you are essentially adding whatever is in the dt to the actual db. It gets the columns from the datagridview.

Comment: so having less number of columns in the gridview display part doesnt affect this update statement.. Is that what your answer is ?

Comment: Correct, unless the columns that are not in the datagridview are not nullable. In that case, it will not update and should throw an error

Comment: I didn't get the last point ..."unless the columns that are not in the datagridview are not nullable"....... what do you mean from this statement ? For eg: I have 10 columns but I display only 5 columns in the datagrid view... Is ther anything need to considered for the datatypes of othe 5 columns not displayed in gridview ?

Comment: In the database, you have the option to make a column not nullable, meaning you cannot input null. If this is the case then the db won't update because that rule is being violated