# Handel new rows added into DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView`  which is populated from a sql server table, Every thing works fine but When I want to save newly added rows by users I can not manage to do it, The fact is that I don't know which event is the best to do it. If I choose `RowsAdded` event it cause problem when at first I load some rows from database and So they start to save again because each time an existing row loads from database `RowsAdded` fires. Then I tried `rowValidating` but the same problem exists.

What is the best way to handel new added rows to a datagridview with considering some existing data that loads into datagridview when form loads?
I have the same problem with editing data too,
Can you please give me some help about it?

Comment: Responding to events and saving each new row, edit and/or delete is not necessary (but sometimes a good idea).  If you are using a DataTable and Adapter you can save all changes en masse now and then like when the user clicks a save button.  Otherwise this is pretty broad and perhaps opinion based.

Comment: [CRUD Operations using DataGridView, DataTable and TableAdapter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36274706/3110834)

Comment: @RezaAghaei thanks my friend,This was exactly what I need

Comment: @Plutonix thanks for your hint.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Wow..Sorry, I had forgot it, I voted it up.Thanks

Comment: @MajidHojati No problem, thank for the feedback :)