# Converting an empty null integer from datagridview and store into database

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Hi everyone i have this codes that read a datagridview to database.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NxtKinNum", Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value));
```

The row that was added is empty cell and i tried to add this into the database where the value of this is an integer... How do i set it to store a null into the database or is it not possible to do that? Thanks

Comment: You don't need to convert the value to integer. When the value of the cell is an integer, the integer will be inserted. Also if the value is `DBNull.Value` the the null value will be inserted into the column. 

So it's enough to add parameter this way:

    `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NxtKinNum", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume the database you are using is SQLServer. There is a separate Null type for it called `DBNull`. If you want to insert a null for a column if you get a null in a value, you should check if the value is empty or null and then insert DBNull instead.

Something like this

```
 if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
 {
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NxtKinNum", DBNull.Value);
 }
 else
 {
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NxtKinNum", value);
 }
```

Edit: If you are binding a datasource to the DataGridView, then for cells with nulls, the default cell value is DBNull. In that case, you can do what Reza suggested and simply use

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NxtKinNum", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
```

Comment: @NoobCoder Did you try this?

Comment: When the cell is empty, `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value` is exactly `DBNull.Value` and you don't need to do any null checking or conversion.

Comment: I haven't worked on WinForms for sometime, but I remember running into this issue and using the solution I mentioned. Have you tried the solution you suggested @RezaAghaei?

Comment: Read my Answer to see the correct solution. Also take a look at linked post.(BTW if you not mention my in the comments, I'll not be informed about the message.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159776/discussion-between-mohamed-najiullah-and-reza-aghaei).

Comment: @RezaAghaei can we discuss this in chat?

Comment: @MohamedNajiullah Chat is not efficient enough. You can ask any question in comments :) Also the code can be simply tested.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, ok. I just wanted to know if you were saying the code snippet I posted wouldn't work?

Comment: Yes, the last paragraph of your answer is wrong. `Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value)` will not work in cases the cell contains null.

Comment: Right. Because null cannot be converted to an int. I overlooked that. I thought you were talking about my first snippet. I'll change it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert the value to integer. When the value of the field is an integer, the integer will be inserted. Also if the value is `DBNull.Value` the the null value will be inserted into the column.

So it's enough to add parameter this way:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NxtKinNum", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
```

**Note**

You can make CRUD operations easier if you use `TableAdapter`. Take a look at this post for example [CRUD Operations using DataGridView, DataTable and TableAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36274706/3110834)

Comment: Hi assuming there is an integer instead of null value will this code still work?

Comment: tested your method before but i think they told me its the wrong format

Comment: The wrong solution is checking for the type. This is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

First Of All, In your table design "YourColumnName" should be "Allow Null".

**`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NxtKinNum",dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value==null ? DBNull.Value : dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);`**

If cell value is null then store null value in table else store the value of datagridview Cell.